# BCP utility in SQL Server - how to exclude tabs in the output

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I use a view to get financial data and in the view it pads the columns into a positional file. Then I use BCP to create the file. All gr8 but I do not know how to stop it adding TABS to the file. Any idea how to stop / exclude tabs?

```
set @Command = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM AscendancyCF.dbo.[BACS_EXPORT]" queryout "C:\bcp\edge_bacs_pay_' + @sDate +  '.dat" -T -c -S' + @@SERVERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

By TABS, I'm guessing you mean it's using tab spacing as the delimiter. You need to specify the delimiter switch (-t,) in your query:

```
set @Command = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM AscendancyCF.dbo.[BACS_EXPORT]" queryout "C:\bcp\edge_bacs_pay_' + @sDate +  '.dat" -T -c -t, -S' + @@SERVERNAME
```